# define/create map from constructor

Tags: javascript

You can create an Object like this

```
var o = {
  9 : 'dh',
  test : 'wee'
};
```

How to create a map? (I want to keep the key order)

```
var m = new Map({
  9 : 'dh',
  test : 'wee'
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor takes an iterable of *key-value pairs*, expressed two-element arrays:

```
var myMap = new Map([['key1', 'value1'], ['key2', 'value2']]);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#Relation_with_Array_objects